# JavaFX/Maven app run but it doesn't show

Tags: java, maven, javafx

My application (JavaFX - Java 8) consumes a REST service and need Jersey libs (2.17). Depedencies are managed by Maven, this is my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance-repackaged</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-debug-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi-resource-locator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven_compiler_source>1.8</maven_compiler_source>
        <maven_compiler_target>1.8</maven_compiler_target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When i run the app, it run without errors or warnings (i can see a clear output in eclipse console), i run it from cmd for see errors, but no one. The app run (can see the process) but it doesn't show.

[image]

Maybe JavaFX and Maven are not compatible? Should i have to create a JavaFX project instead Maven project? If i have, how i can add a **folder lib** and not all JARs directly?

I appreciated any help.

Comment: Check the log file for that JVM. Should tell you something.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It look's like a Maven incompatibility with JavaFX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was only add a few lines:

Just add the Main class:

```
<main.class>me.localtest.views.Main</main.class>
```

And add the Maven package plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The pom.xml was thus:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>me.localtest</groupId>
    <artifactId>CustomersAppClient</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>CustomersAppClient</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance-repackaged</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-debug-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi-resource-locator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven_compiler_source>1.8</maven_compiler_source>
        <maven_compiler_target>1.8</maven_compiler_target>
        <!-- name of the jar -->
        <jar.final.name>CustomersApp</jar.final.name>
        <!-- class name -->
        <main.class>me.localtest.views.Main</main.class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${jar.final.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Mavven package plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

No need Zen JavaFX plugin anymore. Hope this help to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the problem is the packaging of the jar. You need to package a `runnable jar` and not an ordinary jar.

You have many options to build one, the best being using [`JavaFX Maven Plugin`](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You will find everything you need to know in the [documentation](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/jar-bundle.html)

You can also use a `maven-assembly-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will create a jar with `ProjectName-Version-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` inside your target folder.

You can run the jar on double clicking on it or using the following command in the terminal:

```
java -jar jarName
```