# How can I install maven repository into your pom.xml file in netbeans 8.0.2?

Tags: maven-3, javafx-8, netbeans-8

Should I manually install maven in netbeans 8.0.2?I have try to find pom.xml but i can not find it!In my netbeans services show maven repository.how can i add dependency in maven?

Comment: You need to create a new Maven Project. It will automatically create the `pom.xml` file for you, where you can add your dependencies. For more information, visit the [official tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/maven-hib-java-se.html#03).

Comment: But Maven project don't have "JavaFXML Application" option.How can I add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a `JavaFX FXML Application` while you are creating a `Maven based JavaFX application using Netbeans`. Since JavaFX (i.e. jfxrt.jar) is already present in the default classpath with JDK 8, you do not need any external modification to run a JavaFX application.

Few things that may come in handy :

- Just make sure that your project is running on JDK 8, you add a [`maven-compiler-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) and set the [source/target to 1.8](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).
- Maven will **not** pick your fxml files if you add them in `src/main/java`. Always add your java files in the said directory and all the *FMXL files must go inside `src/main/resources`*.
- If you need further help for packaging and deploying your application you can use the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin). A short tutorial can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435054/javafx-maven-app-run-but-it-doesnt-show/29435889#29435889).